# How to compare date (month/year) with another date (month/year)

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

How to compare parts of date in Informix DBMS:

I wrote the following query but I get a syntax error:

```
select id,name from h_history 
 where ( h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH >= 2/2012 )
   and ( h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH <= 1/2013 )
```

I wanna to compare with year and month

How to do this?

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Is `h_date` a datetime field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to use the DATETIME route, you need to format the values correctly.  As it is, you've written:

```
select id,name from h_history 
 where ( h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH >= 2/2012 )
   and ( h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH <= 1/2013 )
```

The `2/2012` is an integer division equivalent to 0, and there's no implicit cast from integers to datetime or vice versa.

You could write:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT id, name
  FROM h_history 
 WHERE (h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH >= DATETIME(2012-02) YEAR TO MONTH)
   AND (h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH <= DATETIME(2013-01) YEAR TO MONTH)
```

That's verbose but precise.  You could use a short-cut:

```
-- Query 2
SELECT id, name
  FROM h_history 
 WHERE (h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH >= '2012-02')
   AND (h_date::DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH <= '2013-01')
```

However, since `h_date` is a DATE rather than a DATETIME X TO Y type, there are other options available.  The YEAR, MONTH, DAY functions extract the obvious parts from a DATE (and, if you pass a DATETIME to the function, then the DATETIME will be coerced into a DATE and then processed).  The only fully locale-independent DATE constructor is the MDY function which takes 3 arguments, the month, day and year.  All string representations are subject to interpretation by locale, and therefore won't work everywhere all the time.

You can also do:

```
-- Query 3
SELECT id, name
  FROM h_history 
 WHERE (h_date >= MDY(2,  1, 2012))
   AND (h_date <= MDY(1, 31, 2013))
```

Or:

```
-- Query 4
SELECT id, name
  FROM h_history 
 WHERE ((YEAR(h_date) = 2012 AND MONTH(h_date) >= 2) OR YEAR(h_date) >= 2013)
   AND ((YEAR(h_date) = 2013 AND MONTH(h_date) <= 1) OR YEAR(h_date) <  2013)
```

Or:

```
-- Query 5
SELECT id, name
  FROM h_history 
 WHERE (YEAR(h_date) * 100 + MONTH(h_date)) >= 201202
   AND (YEAR(h_date) * 100 + MONTH(h_date)) <= 201301
```

---

Given the choice, I'd probably use Query 2 as succinct but accurate, or perhaps Query 5, but all of queries 1-5 are usable.

If `h_date` was a column of some DATETIME type and you need to compare parts of a DATETIME, you can either use casting (as shown in Query 1) or the EXTEND function.  That tends to be verbose.

Comment: Oh yeah; if it was another DBMS, I'd be worried, but I'm confident of Informix (unless I've made a typo).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  id,name 
FROM h_history 
WHERE
  h_date >= MDY(2, 1, 2012)
  AND h_date < MDY(2, 1, 2013)
```

Comment: how it the month >2 and <1 !!
it gives me false all the time

Comment: It'd be `< MDY(1,1,2013)` but the answer is still valid

Comment: @swasheck The original question, as I understood it, was `<=2012/01`, that is include all rows from january?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `h_date` is a proper date field, why wouldn't

```
SELECT 
      id
    , name
FROM h_history 
WHERE h_date >= '02/01/2012' and h_date <= '01/31/2013'
```

work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table t where MONTH(t.date) = 12
```

Comment: for example the date of column is available in my table "user" so the way to compare only the month of that date column